# Why do I get an ORA-24247 with code in function but not in anonymous block?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a simple function to verify whether a url is valid.

I started with an anonymous block that looks like;

```
DECLARE
  httpuri HTTPURIType;
  y CLOB;
  x BLOB;
BEGIN
  httpuri := HTTPURIType('http://google.com');
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(httpuri.getContentType());
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Bad Url');
  END;

END;
/
```

This works fine, it outputs a "Bad Url" when the url is bad, and the mime type other wise.

Great let's write a function to encapsulate everything;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CHECK_URL 
(
  URL_IN IN VARCHAR2 
) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
  HTTPURI HTTPURIType;
  OUT_STRING VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  HTTPURI := HTTPURITYPE(URL_IN);
  BEGIN
    OUT_STRING := HTTPURI.GETCONTENTTYPE();
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
     OUT_STRING := 'Error: Bad URL-' || URL_IN;
  END;
  RETURN OUT_STRING;
END CHECK_URL;
```

I call it with;

```
SELECT CHECK_URL('http://google.com') FROM DUAL;
```

or

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHECK_URL('http://google.com'));
END;
/
```

This always returns "Error: Bad URL-" followed by the url entered. When I take out the exception handler, it gives the following error;

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.HTTPURITYPE", line 123
ORA-06512: at "LMSADMIN.CHECK_URL", line 10
29273. 00000 -  "HTTP request failed"
*Cause:    The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
*Action:   Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.
           Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.
```

I have a minimal understanding of ACL lists. I am running both sets of code as the same user so I am not sure why I get differing results.

Edit: Database Version - 12c R2.

Comment: Are ACL/privs granted directly to the function owner, or via a role?

Comment: Has to be something with privileges.

Comment: As I mentioned I have a minimal understanding of ACLs. How can I tell?

Comment: I tried running the select statement (the function) as sys, with the same result.

Comment: ACL's work differently between Oracle 11g and 12c, you should add your database version.

Comment: DB Version - 12c R2